# AbstractGoogleClient - Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, spring-cloud-gcp

How can i set GCP Application name?

```
2018-Nov-22 11:18:18.283 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-9] 
c.g.a.c.g.s.AbstractGoogleClient - Application name is not set. 
Call 
Builder#setApplicationName.
```

I have following constructor in my class.

```
private final GoogleCredential googleCredential;
private final String projectId;
private final String zone;
private final String region;

private GcpClient(GcpAccountSettings settings) throws 
  GcpClientException {
    try {
        this.googleCredential = 
  getCredential(settings.getClientEmail(), 
  settings.getPrivateKey());
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        throw new GcpClientException(e);
    }

    this.projectId = settings.getProjectId();
    this.zone = settings.getZone();
    this.region = settings.getRegions();
}
```

Im really hoping your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set application name like following.

```
 Compute compute =
            new Compute.Builder(googleCredential.getTransport(), 
 googleCredential.getJsonFactory(), googleCredential)
                    .setApplicationName(projectId).build();
```

if you need more details please follow below link 
[how to set application name](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start)